# Facing "Converting byte[] to Kafka Connect data failed due to serialization error" in kafka connect

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

I am facing "Converting byte[] to Kafka Connect data failed due to serialization error" while working with debezium as source connector and kafka connect (Jdbc Sink connector) as sink connector. I am working with these following files:

1. connect-standalone-file.properties

```
bootstrap.servers=localhost:9092

key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
key.converter.schemas.enable=false
value.converter.schemas.enable=true

offset.storage.file.filename=/tmp/connect.offsets

plugin.path=/dir/kafka_2.12-3.2.3/libs
```

2. Source Connetor

```
name=inventory-connector-test31
connector.class=io.debezium.connector.oracle.OracleConnector
tasks.max=1
database.server.name=server1
database.hostname=***.**.*.*
database.port=1521
database.user=username
database.password=password
database.dbname=dbname
database.pdb.name=ORCLPDB1
database.connection.adapter=logminer
database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers=localhost:9092
database.history.kafka.topic=schema-changes.inventory
#snapshot.mode=SCHEMA_ONLY_RECOVERY
transforms=filter,route
transforms.filter.type=io.debezium.transforms.Filter
transforms.filter.language=jsr223.groovy
transforms.filter.condition=value.source.table == 'CUSTOMERS' && ((value.before != null && value.before.ID >= 1000 && value.before.ID <= 2000) || (value.after != null && value.after.ID >= 1000 && value.after.ID <= 2000))
transforms.filter.topic.regex=server1.DEBEZIUM.*
transforms.route.type=org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.RegexRouter
transforms.route.regex=([^.]+)\\.([^.]+)\\.([^.]+)
transforms.route.replacement=$3
```

3. Sink Connector:

```
name=students-sink14
connector.class=io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector
tasks.max=1
topics=CUSTOMERS
connection.url=jdbc:postgresql://ipaddr:5432/productorcl?user=username&password=pass
transforms=unwrap
transforms.unwrap.type=io.debezium.transforms.ExtractNewRecordState
transforms.unwrap.drop.tombstones=false
auto.create=true
insert.mode=upsert
delete.enabled=true
pk.mode=record_key
```

Complete Error I am facing is:

```
org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Tolerance exceeded in error handler
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndHandleError(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:223)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execute(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:149)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.convertAndTransformRecord(WorkerSinkTask.java:513)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.convertMessages(WorkerSinkTask.java:493)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.poll(WorkerSinkTask.java:332)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.iteration(WorkerSinkTask.java:234)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.execute(WorkerSinkTask.java:203)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:188)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:243)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.DataException: Converting byte[] to Kafka Connect data failed due to serialization error: 
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter.toConnectData(JsonConverter.java:324)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.Converter.toConnectData(Converter.java:88)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.lambda$convertAndTransformRecord$3(WorkerSinkTask.java:513)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndRetry(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:173)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndHandleError(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:207)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unrecognized token 'Struct': was expecting (JSON String, Number, Array, Object or token 'null', 'true' or 'false')
 at [Source: (byte[])"Struct{ID=1001}"; line: 1, column: 8]
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonDeserializer.deserialize(JsonDeserializer.java:66)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter.toConnectData(JsonConverter.java:322)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unrecognized token 'Struct': was expecting (JSON String, Number, Array, Object or token 'null', 'true' or 'false')
 at [Source: (byte[])"Struct{ID=1001}"; line: 1, column: 8]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser._constructError(JsonParser.java:2391)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._reportError(ParserMinimalBase.java:745)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser._reportInvalidToken(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:3635)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser._handleUnexpectedValue(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:2734)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser._nextTokenNotInObject(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:902)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser.nextToken(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:794)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readTreeAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4703)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readTree(ObjectMapper.java:3090)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonDeserializer.deserialize(JsonDeserializer.java:64)
    ... 18 more
```

Can you please identify where am I going wrong ?

Comment: The error is related to your schemas.enable=true setting

Comment: I wast sure if this error was gone because I edit that thing to false or addition of "errors.tolerance=all" to my sinker.

Comment: The error tolerance config can hide/ignore the error, not fix anything. The error itself is saying there's a schema issue